# How to build the simplest ALSA MIDI sequencer in C: a metronome?

Tags: libalsa

I'd like to build a very simple metronome capturing notes for tap tempo then emitting NOTE ON events.
I'm OK with capturing but what is the good way to sequence notes with ALSA from C?
Like just quarters?

Thanks.